# codeigniter transaction is not working

Tags: codeigniter, transition

I am using codeigniter transaction. i wrote a function but it is not working.It was supposed to complete the transaction while submitting my form. Now its not saving with this code.with out transition code it is working. how can i fix this:

```
  public function twotable_insertData() {
            $this->db->trans_start();
            $data = array(
                'brand_name' => $this->input->post('f_name'),
                'brand_user_name' => $this->input->post('l_name'),

            );

            $brand_id = $this->m_common->insert_row('brands', $data);
            echo '$brand_id';
            $data1 = array(
                'brand_id' => $brand_id,
                'stadium_id' => $this->input->post('stadium'),
                'concession_stand_no' => $this->input->post('con_std_no'),

            );
            $this->m_common->insert_row('concession_stands', $data1);
            redirect('backend/brand/view_brand');
            if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
                $this->db->trans_rollback();
            } else {
               echo $this->db->trans_complete();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting `brand_id`

Comment: yes i am saving this brand_id in another table....

Comment: You  are redirecting before `if` condition you may need to place if condition before redirection

Comment: ok.. but i am saving my data in two table... for this how do i have to use if condition??can you please re-edit my post??

Comment: Put redirection after `$this->db->trans_rollback();` line, or even after `if(){}else{}` block. See what better suits your need. Also, `echo '$brand_id';` probably need to be `echo "$brand_id";`.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your query...

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$data = array(
    'brand_name' => $this->input->post('f_name'),
    'brand_user_name' => $this->input->post('l_name')
);

$brand_id = $this->m_common->insert_row('brands', $data);
//  echo '$brand_id';
$data1 = array(
            'brand_id' => $brand_id,
            'stadium_id' => $this->input->post('stadium'),
            'concession_stand_no' => $this->input->post('con_std_no')
);
$this->m_common->insert_row('concession_stands', $data1);
$this->db->trans_complete();
if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
   // Check if transaction result successful
   $this->db->trans_rollback();
   $this->session->set_flashdata('failure', 'Transaction Fails.');
}else{
   $this->db->trans_complete();
   $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Transaction Success.');
}
   redirect('backend/brand/view_brand');
```

Comment: where do i have to write my insert query??